# Creating a node for a LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I am trying to create a queue of nodes. Each node will have 2 values (m and n). Relatively new to Java and wanted to know how can I create/implement a queue of nodes in which each node has a set of 2 int values (m, n).

Comment: You should encapsulate the two values in a own class. Name it appropriately, and also name the member-properties appropriately so the reader of your code knows what to expect. Then just use the class (which holds the properties) in your LinkedList.

Comment: [`Queue<MyNode> myQueue = new ArrayDeque<MyNode>()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: Thanks!. The user will be inputing 2 int values - m and n. Theses 2 values need to be added as a single node in the queue. Could you elaborate on how to code this? @theomega

Comment: @KeshavSharma Do you know how to create a class with fields? If yes, then do that. If no, read further in your Java guide.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be as follows:

```
Node {
  DataType m;
  DataType n;
  Node next; // you use to connect to other nodes in the list
  //constructor{ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple node list:

```
public class List{
   class Node{
      protected int a, b;
      Node next;

      public Node(int a, int b){
         this.a = a;
         this.b = b;
      }

      //some get methods 
   }

   Node root = null;

   public void insertNode(int a, int b){
      new_node = new Node(a, b);

      new_node.next = root;

      root = new_node; 
   }
}
```